# Organize mongoose all output like array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to get a json output of all results like this .

```
["192.168.56.4","192.168.56.152","192.168.56.44","192.168.56.63","192.168.56.13","192.168.56.149","192.168.56.101","192.168.56.16"]
```

```
    something
    .find({}, 
          { _id: 0} )
    .sort({ row: 1 })
    .select( 'ip' )
    .exec(function(err, docs){
        docs = docs.map(function(doc) { return doc.ip; });
        if(err){
            res.json(err)
        } else {
            res.json(docs)
        }
    });
```

And the code provided is working fine to get the result. But the problem is ".map" is not available further more for security reason. May I know the alternative method to get same result. Thank you.